# History comment character

Tags: bash

Whilst tinkering with history settings, I keep seeing references to the 'history comment character' in the man pages. Is this different to using `#` for commenting in Bash?

I can't seem to find an answer as to what actual character code is for the history comment character and how it differs to a conventional bash comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I understand it:

There is the "normal" comment character, `#`, which can't be changed. It indicates the start of a comment in scripts and in interactive sessions (unless the `interactive_comments` shell option is disabled), and everything from that character on is ignored.

The history comment character can be set using `histchars`; the default value is `!^#`.

- `!` is used to indicate history expansion (like "repeat previous command": `!!`)
- `^` is to substitute something in the previous command:

  ```
  $ echo foo foo
  foo foo
  $ ^foo^bar^     # final ^ is optional
  bar foo
  ```
- `#` is the history comment character.

The history comment character is used:

- In `~/.bash_history`, to mark timestamps as comments when `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is set:

  ```
  #1597532894
  echo foo
  #1597532908
  histchars='!^@'
  @1597532918
  vim ~/.bash_history
  ```

  Notice how the timestamp prefix switches to `@` after the second command.
- To skip history substitution for the remaining words on a line:

  ```
  $ echo foo
  foo
  $ echo !$ @ !$ # !$
  foo @ foo
  $ histchars='!^@'
  $ echo foo
  foo
  $ echo !$ @ !$ # !$
  foo @ !$
  ```

  `!$` is "the last word of the previous command". With the default settings (history comment character is `#`), `echo !$ @ !$ # !$` expands to `echo foo @ foo # !$` and prints `foo @ foo`; everything after `#` is ignored. When switching the history comment character to `@`, the second `!$` is not expanded to `foo` any longer.

When would you use that? I honestly don't know, and it really only applies to interactive shell sessions, where the default of `#` make total sense, and anything else would be highly surprising behaviour to me. I can't find anything in the Bash release notes to explain what the intended purpose of being able to separately set the history comment character is.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it provides a really helpful view into how this works. I now understand both what the default history comment character is and where changes to it take effect. Like yourself though, I see no great use for it, but at least, now I know :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using a character aside from the default `#` as the history comment character will allow history substitutions to find the Words in a shell comment.
If you are pasting something to save it, perhaps from the GUI, and it is malformed or not for running in shell, you can still manipulate it with the full set of substitutions and variables, in the comment, without risk of executing it.